# How to sort text field with first two digit numbers

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, sorting

I have below current order in my default column (LinkFilename). I want require orders mentioned in below. How we can do this?

**Current Order:**

- 1_Project Management
- 10_Prototyping
- 11_Marketing
- 12_PilotOrders
- 2_Risk_Management
- 3_Supply_Management

**Required Order:**

- 1_Project Management
- 2_Risk_Management
- 3_Supply_Management
- 10_Prototyping
- 11_Marketing
- 12_PilotOrders

Comment: This is how it works using SharePoint default capabilities. Create another column (probably number column) for sort order and sort the view based on this column.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior in SharePoint. SharePoint sorts the text fields alphabetically (A, B, C, or 1, 2, 3).

**Workaround**:

Create another column (probably number column) for sort order and sort the view based on this column.

---

> If a column isn't sorting accurately, the likely reason is that the column was set up for a different kind of data than it actually contains.
>
> For example, **Numbers** and **Text** are different kinds of data, and each kind is sorted differently. If a Text column contains numerals rather than words, when you sort that column the numbering would be sorted inaccurately, like this:
>
> 1, 11, 12, 2, 21, 22, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ...
>
> You can fix this situation by changing the underlying **Type** setting for the column

**Documentation**: [Use sorting to modify a SharePoint view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-sorting-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-1e85d6e7-bdb3-4176-b1cb-62c5fbd3ef98)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a text field you can simply use 2 digit numbers.

- 01_Project Management
- 02_Risk_Management
- 03_Supply_Management
- 10_Prototyping
- 11_Marketing
- 12_PilotOrders